# 3.22 integration is order preserving. Is my proof for these cases ok? "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.

> 3.8 ***integration is order preserving***
> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a measure space and $f,g:X\to [0,\infty]$ are $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions such that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in X$. Then $\int fd\mu\leq\int gd\mu.$

> 3.20 ***integration is homogeneous***
> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a measure space and $f:X\to [-\infty,\infty]$ is a function such that $\int fd\mu$ is defined. If $c\in\mathbb{R}$, then $$\int cfd\mu=c\int fd\mu.$$

> 3.21 ***additivity of integration***
> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a measure space and $f,g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions such that $\int |f|d\mu<\infty$ and $\int |g|d\mu<\infty$. Then $$\int (f+g)d\mu=\int f d\mu+\int g d\mu.$$

> 3.22 ***integration is order preserving***
> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a measure space and $f,g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions such that $\int fd\mu$ and $\int gd\mu$ are defined. Suppose also that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in X$. Then $\int fd\mu\leq\int gd\mu.$

> Proof The cases where $\int fd\mu=\pm\infty$ or $\int gd\mu=\pm\infty$ are left to the reader.
> $\dots$

I proved the following proposition.
Is my proof ok?

> Proposition:
> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a measure space and $f,g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions such that $\int fd\mu$ and $\int gd\mu$ are defined. Suppose also that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in X$. Suppose $\int fd\mu=\pm\infty$ or $\int gd\mu=\pm\infty$. Then $\int fd\mu\leq\int gd\mu.$

> My proof:
> If $\int fd\mu=-\infty$, then obviously $\int fd\mu\leq\int gd\mu.$
> If $\int gd\mu=+\infty$, then obviously $\int fd\mu\leq\int gd\mu.$
>
> Let $\int fd\mu=+\infty$.
> Then, $+\infty=\int fd\mu=\int f^+d\mu-\int f^-d\mu$.
> So, $\int f^+d\mu=+\infty$ and $\int f^-d\mu\in\mathbb{R}$.
> $f^+(x)-f^-(x)=f(x)\leq g(x)$ holds.
> $f^+(x)\leq g(x)+f^-(x)$ holds.
> By 3.8, $\int f^+d\mu\leq \int \left(g+f^-\right)d\mu$ holds.
> By 3.21, $\int f^+d\mu\leq \int gd\mu+\int f^-d\mu$ holds.
> Since $\int f^-d\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, the following inequality is not nonsense and holds:
> $\int fd\mu=\int f^+d\mu-\int f^-d\mu\leq \int gd\mu$.
>
> Let $\int gd\mu=-\infty$.
> Then, $-\infty=\int gd\mu=\int g^+d\mu-\int g^-d\mu$.
> So, $\int g^+d\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\int g^-d\mu=+\infty$.
> $f(x)\leq g(x)=g^+(x)-g^-(x)$ holds.
> $g^-(x)\leq g^+(x)-f(x)$ holds.
> By 3.8, $\int g^-d\mu\leq \int (g^+-f)d\mu$ holds.
> By 3.20 and 3.21, $\int g^-d\mu\leq \int g^+d\mu-\int fd\mu$ holds.
> Since $\int g^-d\mu=+\infty$, $\int g^+d\mu-\int fd\mu=+\infty$.
> Since $\int g^+d\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, $\int fd\mu=-\infty$.
> So, $\int fd\mu=\int gd\mu.$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info Please point the specific step(s) you doubt and why. This site is not meant as a proof-checking machine.

Comment: @AnneBauval I am new to this type of problem. So I am not sure if my solution is ok or not. And I think the cases $\int fd\mu=\pm\infty$ or $\int gd\mu=\pm\infty$ are more difficult than the case $\int fd\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\int gd\mu\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I understand, but this does not answer the question of where you are "not sure".

Comment: Note that the second case reduces to the first one by considering $-g\le-f.$ That said, your proof is fine.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much for your answer. I cannot say where I am not sure precisely. I am not familiar with calculation like $0\cdot\infty=\infty\cdot 0=0$. And the author didn't write calculation rule such as $r + \infty=\infty$. (But we can guess the rules.) The only exception is $0\cdot\infty=\infty\cdot 0=0$. The author wrote "We adopt the convention that $0\cdot\infty$ and $\infty\cdot 0$ should both be interpreted to be $0$" on p.74 in the book.